# Is LinUCB Hannan consistent?

Tags: consistency, multiarmed-bandit, contextual-bandit

I'm going through the textbook Bandit Algorithms, by Lattimore and Szepesvari (http://downloads.tor-lattimore.com/banditbook/book.pdf).

It describes regret bounds for the LinUCB algorithm of the form: with probability $1-\delta$, the regret behaves like 
$$
\hat{R}_T = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{T}\log(T)),
$$
which can be used (along with the bounded regret assumption) to show the expected regret behaves similarly. (See Ch 19, Theorem 19.2)

My understanding is that neither of these results demonstrate that LinUCB *always* achieves sublinear regret. There is always a chance (proportional to $\delta$) that a particular run of the algorithm will produce erroneous confidence bounds in which the optimal arm is excluded from ever being pulled, and regret is linear. (e.g. the index of the optimal arm falls below the true mean of a sub-optimal arm)

Can it be shown that LinUCB, or some variant, converges with probability 1?

(I have found sufficient conditions for which UCB is Hannan consistent here ("Lower Bounds and Selectivity of Weak-Consistent Policies inStochastic Multi-Armed Bandit Problem", Salomon et al 2013), but nothing on LinUCB.)